# Where is Visual Studio 2008 ATL template folder?

Tags: visual-studio

I would like to build a Deskband for Internet Explorer. I found [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/atl/rbdeskband.aspx).

My problem is, how and where is my Visual Studio 2008's template folder so I can put the RBDeskband template.

Comment: That code is from 2001 and it doesn't even mention Visual Studio 2008, it only mentions VC6. But in any way, you have the `ItemTemplate` and `ProjectTemplate` under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE` (there is caching folders, you might need to update them as well).

Comment: i have put the files over there, but still no effects. how to install the RBDeskband wizard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:

Actually I think they must be in

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcprojects
```

Comment: I have follow the tutorial on the website above. But I still could not find where is the installed template :(